# apt-daily timer/service — where did it come from?

Tags: debian, systemd, apt

We are running Debian 9 and today faced the issue that the Redis server (on a couple of instances) was restarted.

Checking the logs, I found two unknown services — `apt-daily` and `apt-daily-upgrade` — both added to the systemd timers:

```
root@main:/home/user# systemctl list-timers
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST                         PASSED       UNIT                         ACTIVATES
...
Tue 2018-06-19 11:50:11 UTC  4h 6min left  Tue 2018-06-19 05:03:10 UTC  2h 40min ago apt-daily.timer              apt-daily.service
Wed 2018-06-20 06:09:32 UTC  22h left      Tue 2018-06-19 06:41:51 UTC  1h 2min ago  apt-daily-upgrade.timer      apt-daily-upgrade.service
```

I can not find any information about those two using `apropos` and Google (although the `apt-daily.service` file has a `Documentation=man:apt(8)` string — but there is nothing about `apt-daily`).

Does anybody know what’s happening here? How can such auto-upgrades be enabled by default?

P.S. I also have Debian 8 — nothing similar there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The timers come from the `apt` package, so they’re installed by default. In a default installation, they only ensure that the indexes are updated every day; this is long-standing behaviour and is also supported by a cron job for systems without systemd.

Package *upgrades*, and the resulting restarts, only happen if [`unattended-upgrades`](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) is installed, and follow that package’s configuration.

See [the relevant section of the Debian Reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_automatic_download_and_upgrade_of_packages) for details.

Comment: Thanks, indeed - all servers have the `unattended-upgrades` installed, and all have `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1"` in its `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` configs.

Comment: Althought... I just started Debian 9 from ISO and it haven't `unattended-upgrades` installed, but have `apt-daily-upgrade.timer` activated...

Comment: @setenvoy the timer is activated, but the service it starts doesn’t upgrade any package if `unattended-upgrades` isn’t installed.