# Why is Debian connecting to a CDN server in the background, automatically?

Tags: debian, software-updates, privacy

I noticed my VM with a fairly barebones Debian 11 install periodically tries to connect to
`debian.map.fastlydns.net` on port 80.

It looks like this domain is what the DNS record of http://deb.debian.org points to (and has [for at least a year](https://old.reddit.com//r/debian/comments/kexgjr/domain_debianmapfastlydnsnet_really_debianrelated/)), so it seems to be a legitimate request somehow related to package update tracking.

But what is doing this? Debian doesn't have a MOTD showing available updates, and it usually seems to need manual running of `apt update` and `apt upgrade` to keep the system current. Could I opt-out of whatever service(s) cause these requests?

Answer (score 2):

`apt` itself sets up a daily `apt update`, even if `unattended-upgrades` isn’t installed; this is presumably what you’re seeing the effects of.

See [apt-daily timer/service — where did it come from?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/450592/86440) for details.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that this may be the `unattended-upgrades` package at work.

From https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades:

> The purpose of unattended-upgrades is to keep the computer current with the latest security (and other) updates automatically.

That simple overview doesn't quite square with my experience, since on all my Debian systems it seems I usually have patches to do in `apt list --upgradeable` until I manually upgrade. But perhaps it is applying *some* (just not *all*) updates on its own?